# What is Atom XML?

Tags: .net, xml, odata, atom-feed

I am working in ODATA Service in .net. I heard that the ODATA service returns both ATOM XML and JSON. I am not sure about ATOM XML.

Can someone please explain what ATOM XML is with an example?

Comment: It is XML based file format http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_%28standard%29

Comment: It's simple enough to check [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_%28standard%29) or search the web for _Atom XML_ to find lots of other explanations.

Comment: What is [Google](http://www.google.com) or [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_%28standard%29)? SO should be your **last resort**, after exhausting your efforts to find an answer, not the very first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Atom is an XML-based file format used to syndicate content. Developed as an alternative to RSS 2.0, it lies within an XML-namespace. An example of an Atom 1.0 feed is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">

<title>Example Feed</title>
<subtitle>A subtitle.</subtitle>
<link href="http://example.org/feed/" rel="self" />
<link href="http://example.org/" />
<id>urn:uuid:60a76c80-d399-11d9-b91C-0003939e0af6</id>
<updated>2003-12-13T18:30:02Z</updated>


<entry>
    <title>Atom-Powered Robots Run Amok</title>
    <link href="http://example.org/2003/12/13/atom03" />
    <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="http://example.org/2003/12/13/atom03.html"/>
    <link rel="edit" href="http://example.org/2003/12/13/atom03/edit"/>
    <id>urn:uuid:1225c695-cfb8-4ebb-aaaa-80da344efa6a</id>
    <updated>2003-12-13T18:30:02Z</updated>
    <summary>Some text.</summary>
            <content type="xhtml">
               <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                  <p>This is the entry content.</p>
               </div>
            </content>
            <author>
                  <name>John Doe</name>
                  <email>johndoe@example.com</email>
           </author>
</entry>
```

source: http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/Atom-XML